# Mongodb gives error when connecting to it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I used mongodb in my other project. It works in that project but doesn't work in this one. [The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp6ez.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB atlas, In your cluster config click on "Network Access" and under "IP Access List" click on edit button and then choose "Add current IP address".